# Combining multiple textures with a white background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

I'd like to sort of "overlay" these shaders, but the only options are mix and add. Allow me to explain.

I made two images, both white background, one with red scribbles and one with blue scribbles, both 1920x1080. Image textures plugged into diffuse was my node setup. I want both scribbles to be added to the plane while the background stays the same color.

If I mix them I get the following:[image]

The red and blue scribbles are now 50% dimmer than they would be on their own, and the white color hasn't changed in intensity.

If I add them I get the following:[image]

The red and blue scribbles are still 50% dimmer than they normally would be (since the white background is being added over each). But the white background is now 2x brighter than normal.

Can I get a result where the white background is normal brightness and both the blue and red scribbles are at normal brightness?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example with two images with a white background:

[image]

To keep the white and mix the two colors you can use a **Color MixRGB** node with **Multiply** as the transfer mode. Then plug that to only one **Diffuse BSDF** shader:
[image]

[image]

Using Multiply as the transfer mode (quoting from the wiki)

> Returns a darker result than either pixel in most cases (except one of them >equals white=1.0). Completely white layers do not change the background at all. >Completely black layers give a black result. The "opposite" to Screen mode.

More info **[here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/render/shader_nodes/color/index.html#color)**

Comment: Genius, this is amazing, thanks a ton. Would you happen to know what it does and how it works?

Comment: All of the secrets are revealed here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Types/Color

Answer (score 5):

You can add a [*Mix* node](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/color/mix.html), and leave it set to mix. Take the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcflM.png) and plug it into the first color socket *Color1* and *Fac*. Plug the [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV1iN.png) into the *Color2* socket.
If the image in the top socket is looking pale, add a color ramp node to the wire going to the *Fac*, and boost the contrast slightly (by moving the black to the right).
[image: cycles material nodes]

---

[image: test image L] [image: test image R]
However with these images that do not have white backgrounds, you would have to crush the black and white in the color ramp node,
[image: colors crushed together in the ColorRamp node]
or just add a *Separate RGB* node. Then pick the channel that has the best difference, in this case the Red channel.

[image: cycles nodes separate RGB node]

Using the *Fac* and color *mix* has the advantage of not returning a darker result than either image, like some of the other color operations will.