# How to change the colors of a two-color texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I want to create paperhanging for my interior scene, and I want the Pattern on my Wallpaper to be Black and everything *else* to be its normal color, I tried but everything I can make is exactly the opposite what I want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you upload the blendfile

Comment: maybe you should set the top texture to non-color, because you are using it as a mask.

Comment: I tried it doesn't really helps

Comment: instead of the mix shader you need the color --> mix RGB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a mask (a black and white image) from the range of values you want to color in your image texture, explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27803/2217).

In the nodes below I used a *ColorRamp* node to select the range of values (the highlights). You could set the interpolation of the color ramp node to *Consent*, but I left it at the default of *Linear* so that there is a smother transition between the original image and the new color.
The output from the color ramp is the mask. Plug that mask in to the *Fac* of the *Mix* node, the bottom socket is the color that all the highlights will be.

[image: material nodes]

I did not have your exact texture, so the stops in your color ramp node may have to be in different spots to select the correct values.

---

Here is the result, using the nodes above.
[image: final result]

Comment: Ok, that works pretty decent, though it also affects the other parts slightly. But what would I do if I would like the glossy shader to be on the place of the Black Diffuse.

Comment: Nevermind already figured it out myself

Answer (score 8):

Set up the nodes as pictured below. Add a ***RGB to BW*** node to make your texture work as a mask for two *Diffuse* shaders. Set up the colors for *Diffuse* shaders. 
[image]

Flip the input sockets of the *Mix Shader* for a reverse result.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting the image texture before hooking it up to diffuse instead of using it as a factor.

Comment: If this doesn't work I sincerely apologize as I'm away from home and posting this from my recent memory on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

To replays the Diffuse Black I plugged my texture through ColorRamp into the Factor of the Mix Shader with Diffuse Node and Glossy Node, I made the Glossy Orange so you could see. Works Great

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot to David, changing the ColorRamp to Constant really helped